# R, imputed data, how to reorder x-axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a noob in working with R.
I'd like to create a barplot with a surveyimputationlist. I can't manage to reoder the x-axis to 'unimportant - less important -important - very important'. I would be very thankful for some help. This is what I've got so far:

````
bureau_imp <- svydesign(ids = ~ 1, data = imp_data, weights = ~ weight, nest = TRUE)

b_imp <- with(bureau_imp, svyby(formula = ~ feeling, by = ~ importance, FUN = svymean))

summary(MIcombine(b_imp)) %>% mutate(names = rownames(.)) %>% 
separate(names, c("importance", "feeling"), sep = ":") %>% 
mutate(feeling = str_remove(feeling, "feeling")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = importance , y = results, fill = feeling)) + 
geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange","beige","green"))```

This is how the graph currently looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKEH7.png

Thanks in advance

Anna
````

Answer (score 0):

You can first order your `importance` variable.

```
# reorder using just `factor` (option 1)
b_imp$importance <- factor(b_imp$importance, 
  levels=c("Unimportant", "Less important", "Important", "Very important")
)

# alternatively (option 2): using `ordered` to created an ordered factor
b_imp$importance <- ordered(
  b_imp$importance, 
  levels=c("Unimportant", "Less important", "Important", "Very important")
)
```

Once the `importance` variable is an ordered, your `ggplot` will honor that order when redering your plots (barplots or otherwise).

Note: Because I do not see a sample of your actual data, you may have to modify the code above. For example "Less important" may actually be "less important" or "Less Important" in your own data. You need to be exact. If you're not sure what the factor levels are, run:

```
levels(b_imp$importance)
```

or:

```
levels(bureau_imp$importance)
```

wherever that column happens to be in.

If you prefer to stick with `dplyr`, you can also do it through `mutate`:

```
b_imp %>%
  # your other dplyr operations are chained here
  ...
  mutate(importance = factor(importance, levels=c("Unimportant", "Less important", "Important", "Very important"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = importance , y = results, fill = feeling)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange","beige","green"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. The problem is, that r says the class of the object is "svyimputationList". When I try to change this to factor with `bureau_imp <- bureau_imp %>% mutate_if(is.svyimputationList, as.factor)` the following error occurs:
Fehler in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : nicht anwendbare Methode für 'tbl_vars' auf Objekt der Klasse "svyimputationList" angewendet.

Therefore when I try the suggested solution it either runs, but changes nothing, or says "Fehler in UseMethod("mutate_") : nicht anwendbare Methode für 'mutate_' auf Objekt der Klasse "svyimputationList" angewendet"

When I check the levels, they seem to be in the right order.

> levels(bureau_imp$importance)
> [1] "unimportant"    "less important" "important"      "very important"

But this is not transferred to the graph. Instead, they are ordered alphabetically.